# Error in deleting a SharePoint Discussion forum topic

Tags: error, event-handlers

I'm getting a "Cannot complete the action" error message when deleting posts from discussion forums on our sharepoint install. This happens to discussion forums at any level in any of the subsites. It's exactly as described in the post below.

http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--general-question-answers-discussion/error-in-deleting-a-sharepoint-discussion-forum-toipc-in-subsite-2856.shtml

The post does actually get deleted but the error message is worrying. Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the ULS logs?

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem and found a solution. I describe the solution at:
http://thith.blogspot.com/2010/06/fix-sharepoints-discussion-board.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed in the February 23, 2010 CU for Windows SharePoint Services. Install that and it will fix the problem.

List of issues this CU fixes can be found here:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978389/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect there is an event receiver attached to the discussion list. I don't know if this the case is by default, or whether you have a custom eventreceiver or an eventreiver added by another (third party) Feature.

Use the object model, or download a tool of CodePlex, to figure out whether any event receivers are attached. If you find one that's attached, use Reflector to see what it's trying to do when you delete an item. Hopefully you will find something useful in there that could help you solve your problem.